# Has the Dashboard Cache Timeout setting been moved?

Tags: 4.7, dashboard, settings

I can't seem to find the Dashboard Cache Timeout setting, which according to my experience and [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/the-user-interface/menu-dashboard-and-dashlets/#the-home-dashboard-dashlets) can be adjusted

> by visiting Administer > System Settings > Misc and editing Dashboard cache timeout.

But this setting is not to be found at that location, neither on my (slightly dated) out-of-the box 4.7.15 install, nor on the [Drupal demo site](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1).

Has this setting been moved or removed as of some version of CiviCRM? If so, how would one go about changing the Dashboard Cache Timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This setting has been moved to each Reports(Access Tab). [Major improvements](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17663) related to dashlet has been done in 4.7.11 version. Hence, if you wish to change the cache timeout.

1. Navigate to any Reports.
2. Click on Access Tab.
3. Enable `Available for Dashboard?` checkbox which displays the setting you need.

[image]

Comment: Ah - thank you - did not know that either!

Comment: So, there's no more site-wide setting and all dashlets default to 60 minutes no matter what?

Comment: yeah, seems to be so done here - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8851/commits/a8f56d7109e2ae12ed502df0c89e5a89893ac3ca